# Почему вызывается метод базового класса?

Tags: c++, классы, virtual

Почему вызывается метод базового класса `showConsol`, если при создании объекта мы явно указываем дочерний класс `Gorod *obj2 = new Gorod`?

```
class Mesto {
private:
    int coord_x;
    int coord_y;
    string name;
public:
    static int count;
    Mesto(int coord_x, int coord_y, string name) {
        this->coord_x = coord_x;
        this->coord_y = coord_y;
        this->name = name;
        count++;
    }

    int getCoord_X() {
        return coord_x;
    }

    int getCoord_Y() {
        return coord_y;
    }

    string getName() {
        return name;
    }

    void setCoord(int coord_x, int coord_y) {
        this->coord_x = coord_x;
        this->coord_y = coord_y;
        this->name = name;
    }

    void showConsol() {
        cout << "Вызывается метод базового класса" << endl;
        cout << "(" << name << ")" << endl;
        cout << "Координаты, X: " << coord_x << " Y: " << coord_y << endl;
    }
};
int Mesto :: count = 0;

class Gorod :public Mesto {
private:
    int naselenie;
public:
    Gorod(int naselenie, int coord_x, int coord_y, string name) :Mesto(coord_x,coord_y, name) {
        this->naselenie = naselenie;
    }
    int getName() {
        return naselenie;
    }

    void setName(int naselenie) {
        this->naselenie = naselenie;
    }

    void showConsol() {
        cout << "Численность населения: " << naselenie << endl;
        Mesto::showConsol();
    }

};

class MyList {
private:
    struct MyElement {
        Mesto *obj;
        MyElement *next;
    };
    MyElement *head;
public:
    MyList() {
        head = NULL;
    }
    void addList(Mesto *bufobj) {
        MyElement *temp = new MyElement;
        temp->obj = bufobj;
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    }
    void printConsol() {
        MyElement *temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            temp->obj->showConsol();
            cout << "\n-------------------------------" << endl;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    ~MyList() {
        while (head != NULL)
        {
            MyElement *temp = head->next;
            delete head;
            head = temp;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    MyList *list = new MyList();
    Mesto *obj1 = new Mesto(1232, 2323, "Безымянное место");
    Gorod *obj2 = new Gorod(123000, 2312312, -34534534, "Минск");
    list->addList(obj1);
    list->addList(obj2);

    list->printConsol();

    list->~MyList();
}
```

Comment: сделайте метод виртуальным.

Comment: я не говорю, что мне нужно, чтобы вызывалось дочерние методы, я спрашиваю почему вызывается из базового, притом, что создаем конкретно создаем объект на дочерний класс и вызываем его метод

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что в списке указано, что в нем хранятся указатели на `Mesto`, так что при вызове *невиртуальных* функций компилятор разрешает их статически, а не динамически.

Вот тут

```
temp->obj->showConsol();
```

компилятор знает, что `obj` - указатель на `Mesto`, и что `showConsol()` - невиртуальная функция, так что сразу выполняет вызов `Mesto::showConsol()` - у него нет никаких оснований выполнять динамическое разрешение вызова этой функции, поскольку в vtable просто нет записи для нее.

Сделайте `showConsol` виртуальной - тогда компилятор создаст код, который при выполнении обратится к vtable, найдет соответствующий адрес и выполнит вызов функции по этому адресу - `Gorod::showConsol()` для `obj2`.

Comment: А что значит "вызов функций выполняется статически"?

Comment: А, всё, теперь понял, тогда такой вопрос, почему, если вызывается метод базового класса, то он берет не свои значения coord_x, coord_y, name а те значения, которые мы передавали в конструктор при создании дочерних классов?

Comment: Ну, если все понятно - закрывайте вопрос, помечая ответ как принятый :)